# key entity in Entity Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

The problem for me is I have an existing datatable "T_store" in my database with 3 field: storeKey, StoreName, StoreDescription. and I now I want to create a MVC 3 app. to map to all this field, I have

```
public int Id {get; }{set;}
public int storeKey {get; }{set;}
public int StoreName {get; }{set;}
public int StoreDescription {get; }{set;}
```

but I got an error if I declare int id, since the existing datatable doesnt have this field ?

any ideas please

Comment: Why do you need Id property ?

Comment: If I dont include Id Property, i wil have this following error 'Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.'

Answer (score 2):

If you want the ID in the entity and in the table, create the ID column in the table. If you want ID only in the entity, use [NotMapped] for the ID property. Also, I guess that you will use `storeKey` as the key for your entity, so you should use `[Key]` on this property.

Comment: I dont want to manually add the ID column, but I've told i have to use the Id property in order to add, delete the datatable

Answer (score 1):

I wonder why you need Id property as your table already has a key column but, I think this will resolve your problem :

```
[NotMapped]
public int Id { get; set; }
[Key]
public int storeKey { get; set; }
public int StoreName { get; set; }
public int StoreDescription { get; set; }
```

Comment: The reason Why I want the add the Id Property because I want to add, delete each row from the datatable, but if I add the [NotMapped] attribute, it complains said that multiple properties appeared to be primary key.